# Bitmap density causing problems

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm doing my own pixel calculations for drawing on the screen, and have a sprite bitmap (4x2 images in one file).  Each image is 100x100, and the overall file is 400x200.  Using the following method my drawing is not pulling the right section of the bitmap, and the placement on the scren isn't quite right:

```
public void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

> Since: API Level 1
>
> Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill
>   the destination rectangle. If the source rectangle is not null, it
>   specifies the subset of the bitmap to draw.
>
> Note: if the paint contains a maskfilter that generates a mask which
>   extends beyond the bitmap's original width/height (e.g.
>   BlurMaskFilter), then the bitmap will be drawn as if it were in a
>   Shader with CLAMP mode. Thus the color outside of the original
>   width/height will be the edge color replicated.
>
> This function ignores the density associated with the bitmap. This is
>   because the source and destination rectangle coordinate spaces are in
>   their respective densities, so must already have the appropriate
>   scaling factor applied.
>
> Parameters
>
> bitmap > The bitmap to be drawn
>
> src > May be null. The subset of the bitmap to be drawn
>
> dst > The rectangle that the bitmap will be scaled/translated to fit into
>
> paint > May be null. The paint used to draw the bitmap

```
Rect source = new Rect();
    source.left = (this.currentFrame % 4) * 100;
    source.right = source.left + 100;
    source.top = (this.currentFrame / 4) * 100;
    source.bottom = source.top + 100;

    Rect dest = new Rect();
    dest.top = (int) top;
    dest.left = (int) left;
    dest.right = dest.left + 100;
    dest.bottom = dest.top + 100;

    // draw current frame onto canvas
    //canvas.drawBitmap(pics[this.currentFrame], left, top, painter);
    canvas.drawBitmap(pics[0], source, dest, painter);
```

The documentation explicity says densities are ignored, but why is my image being scaled?

Comment: How exactly are you loading pics[0]? Have you tried getResources().openRawResource(imageId)?

Comment: I haven't got the code to hand at the moment, will check later.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Renard - that did the trick, although now I relaise Android was only trying to help me deal with different densities.  Still, it makes doing sprites a real pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Renard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1272824/renard)

How exactly are you loading `pics[0]`? Have you tried `getResources().openRawResource(imageId)`?

This solved my problem.